# ANES catalog inaccessible via lodown

Tags: r, survey

The *lodown* package no longer seems able to download the ANES catalog.

```
> anes_cat <- get_catalog("anes", output_dir = file.path(path.expand("~"), 
"ANES"), your_email = "myemail@myplace.com")

building catalog for anes

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: Have you read the website notice? https://electionstudies.org/data-center/

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the changes at the ANES site require a complete re-write if the `get_catalog_anes`. Perhaps @Anthony_Damico will attend to it when he gets time?

Comment: @AnthonyDamico: I'm reasonably sure the `get_catalog_anes` needs to be re-written to allow password entry and to access different facilities at the ANES site than it currently does.